# how do I to retrieve the value of a hidden input[type=submit] from my servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

As the title says, how do I to retrieve the value of a hidden input[type=submit] from my servlet ?

I've tried this line, but it wouldn't work for me, **ModifPost** servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    String type = (String) request.getAttribute("type");
}
```

knowing that I have this in my JSP :

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value="/modifpost"/>" class="sansRetourLigne">
    <input type="text" disabled style="visibility: hidden;" class="sansRetourLigne" name="type" value="p" />
</form>
```

**web.xml** :

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ModifPost</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.forum.servlets.ModifPost</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ModifPost</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/modifpost</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Why in earth are you trying to retrieve a request parameter as a request attribute? Which resource did you use to learn JSP/Servlets? I'd strongly question the quality of that resource. Or if you didn't use a learning resource at all, but are blindly stabbing around in the dark, then please stop it and go get yourself a decent learning resource on the subject. Our tag wiki page is a good starting point. Put your mouse on top of `[servlets]` tag below the question until a black box shows up and then click therin the *info* link.

Comment: By the way, a "hidden input" is not an input which is hidden by CSS, but whose `type` is really `hidden`. Also, in contraty to whatever you said in the title, that's not an `input type=submit`, but an `input type=text`. So next to servlets, I'd suggest to also take some time apart to learn basic HTML.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Sorry, I code from the morning and I'm not so focused. By the way, can you suggest me some good tutorials please ?

Comment: They are mentioned in our Servlets tag wiki page. I also suggest to just delete this question altogether as it isn't useful to anyone (a too obvious typo/mistake).

Comment: xD I really need to take a break. Can I add you in my contacts please ?

Comment: Sorry, no. Just press "Ask Question" whenever you've a concrete question. Maybe I'll comment or answer it, maybe not.

Comment: I've changed the way in which I get the data. But I still have a problem, I got a **null** value from that **input** knowing that he already has an initial value.

Comment: Do you know that disabled HTML inputs don't send their value to server?

Comment: The input in your example will never be sent when the form is posted because it is disabled.  Instead, use a "type=hidden" input (as mentioned by balusC) that is not disabled.